# Studio MAKE HTTP REQUEST return sid

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

This is from a Studio Flow.

I'd like to return the conversation sid.  The same "sid" that is used in the Twilio log system.  This sid is returned when the conversation is created via a REST call.  On the screen below, you can see that I've figured out how to return some flow.data values using this widget.  When I look through the available sids (the list is long, but there were approximately six different variable.variable.sid type variables to choose from), none of them seem to return the value that I am looking for.  I did add all of them into the JSON return packet and only two returned values.  Both values were not what I was looking for.

I'm hopeful that it is something simple like {{message.sid}}, but just haven't discovered the correct variable name yet.

[image: Twilio Studio MAKE HTTP REQUEST]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want: {{flow.sid}} for the Studio Execution SID.